# Opening new window while out of focus using "keyboard"

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I am trying to track my keypresses, using the module "keyboard" while a PySide2 Widget is not in focus, which works fine. However when I try to create a new Widget using a "keyboard" shortcut the program crashes. Opening a window on a button press works fine. I can also call non UI functions using "keyboard" eg. the print function without any problem.

Do you know a way to fix this and open a new window using "keyboard" or any other method, while a PySide2 window is not in focus. In this example I want to open a new window on "CTRL+D". The Problem exists both for PySide2 and PyQt5.

This is my shortened code:

```
import sys
import json
import os
import keyboard
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QKeySequenceEdit, QLabel, QPushButton, QShortcut
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QObject, Signal, Slot # Qt.Key_W beispielsweise

#from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QKeySequenceEdit, QLabel, QPushButton, QShortcut
#from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal as Signal, pyqtSlot as Slot # Qt.Key_W beispielsweise


class ConfigWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()
        self.init_shortcuts()
        self.show()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300, 400, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("Settings")
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.keyseq = QKeySequenceEdit("CTRL+D")
        grid.addWidget(self.keyseq, 0, 0)

        s_button = QPushButton("Safe")
        grid.addWidget(s_button, 1, 0)

        cl_button = QPushButton("Close")
        grid.addWidget(cl_button, 1, 1)
        cl_button.clicked.connect(self.close)

        open_button = QPushButton("openw")
        grid.addWidget(open_button, 2, 0)
        open_button.clicked.connect(self.call_item_parser)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event): #event:PySide2.QtGui.QKeyEvent
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

    # shortcuts are listened to, while program is running
    def init_shortcuts(self):
        str_value = self.keyseq.keySequence().toString()
        print("Binding _price_keyseq to {}".format(str_value))
        keyboard.add_hotkey(str_value, self.call_item_parser)
        # keyboard.add_hotkey(str_value, print, args=("this works")) # this would work


    def call_item_parser(self):
        self.h_w = ParseWindow()
        self.h_w.setWindowTitle("New Window")
        self.h_w.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.h_w.show()


class ParseWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = ConfigWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused because the callback registered in keyboard is executed in a secondary thread as can be verified by modifying the following part of the code and printing `threading.current_thread()`. In Qt it is forbidden to create any widget in another thread since they are not thread-safe.

```
def call_item_parser(self):
    print(threading.current_thread())
    self.h_w = ParseWindow()
    self.h_w.setWindowTitle("New Window")
    self.h_w.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
    self.h_w.show()
```

```
print(threading.current_thread())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = ConfigWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140144979916608)>
Binding _price_keyseq to ctrl+a
<Thread(Thread-10, started daemon 140144220817152)>
```

One possible solution is to use a signal to send the information to the main thread, and invoke the callback in the main thread.

```
import sys
from functools import partial
import platform
import threading

import keyboard


from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QObject, Signal, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QGridLayout,
    QKeySequenceEdit,
    QPushButton,
)


class KeyBoardManager(QObject):
    activated = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._callbacks = dict()
        self.activated.connect(self._handle_activated)

    @property
    def callbacks(self):
        return self._callbacks

    def register(self, shortcut, callback, *, args=(), kwargs=None):
        self.callbacks[shortcut] = (callback, args, kwargs or {})
        keyboard.add_hotkey(shortcut, partial(self.activated.emit, shortcut))

    @Slot(str)
    def _handle_activated(self, shortcut):
        values = self.callbacks.get(shortcut)
        if values is not None:
            callback, args, kwargs = self._callbacks[shortcut]

            callback(*args, **kwargs)


class ConfigWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()
        self.init_shortcuts()
        self.show()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("Settings")
        grid = QGridLayout(self)

        self.keyseq = QKeySequenceEdit("CTRL+A")
        grid.addWidget(self.keyseq, 0, 0)

        s_button = QPushButton("Safe")
        grid.addWidget(s_button, 1, 0)

        cl_button = QPushButton("Close")
        grid.addWidget(cl_button, 1, 1)
        cl_button.clicked.connect(self.close)

        open_button = QPushButton("openw")
        grid.addWidget(open_button, 2, 0)
        open_button.clicked.connect(self.call_item_parser)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):  # event:PySide2.QtGui.QKeyEvent
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

    # shortcuts are listened to, while program is running
    def init_shortcuts(self):
        self.keyboard_manager = KeyBoardManager()

        str_value = self.keyseq.keySequence().toString()
        if platform.system() == "Linux":
            str_value = str_value.lower()
        print("Binding _price_keyseq to {}".format(str_value))
        self.keyboard_manager.register(str_value, self.call_item_parser)

    def call_item_parser(self):
        print(threading.current_thread())
        self.h_w = ParseWindow()
        self.h_w.setWindowTitle("New Window")
        self.h_w.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.h_w.show()


class ParseWindow(QWidget):
    pass


def main():
    print(threading.current_thread())
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ConfigWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140037641176896)>
Binding _price_keyseq to ctrl+a
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140037641176896)>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and code example. This works